# "approcher" ou "s'approcher"

Tags: sens, usage, verbes-pronominaux

J'ai vu dans un dictionnaire que *approcher* et *s'approcher* peuvent signifier "to approach" en anglais d'une manière intransitive tous les deux. Alors, peut-on dire

> Je suis content que les vacances approchent.

et

> Je suis content que les vacances s'approchent.

tous les deux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Approcher* veut dire  « devenir plus proche de quel­que chose » et on l'emploie plutôt avec un sujet non animé :

> Je suis content que les vacances approchent.

*S’approcher* veut dire « se déplacer pour être plus proche » et donc s’uti­li­se plutôt avec un sujet agissant (donc animé).

> Le petit garçon s'approcha du chien pour le caresser.

Employer *s'approcher* à la place d'*approcher* introduit un effet stylistique. En disant « les vacances s'approchent » je donne vie aux vacances.

Quand le sujet et le complément sont animés on ne peut pas toujours utiliser l'un à la place de l'autre sans en changer le sens.

- > Je me suis approché du directeur pour lui faire part de mes idées sur la gestion de l'entreprise.

  Veut dire que j'ai été physiquement en contact avec, j'ai fait des pas vers, le directeur dans le but de lui parler.
- > J'ai approché le directeur pour lui faire part de mes idées sur la gestion de l'entreprise.

  Veut dire que j'ai eu un contact avec le directeur, mais cela n'implique pas un contact forcément *de visu*, je peux lui avoir écrit, lui avoir fait remettre un mémo par la secrétaire, lui avoir parlé au téléphone, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes. "S'approcher" est une forme réflexive qui insiste sur le mouvement entre l'objet/la personne et sa destination. Vu que "des vacances" ne sont pas réellement mobiles (c'est le temps qui passe), j'utiliserais plutôt la première formulation. Cependant, rien n'empêche de donner un peu de "vie" aux vacances, par exemple en disant: "Les vacances s'approchent à grands pas!".