# Approcher vs. s’approcher

Tags: verbes-pronominaux

I’ve studied this quite a bit, and can’t seem to get my head around the difference between these two verbs. I hear that approcher isn’t used much anymore, and s’approcher mostly takes the spotlight. Is this true? Can someone explain the subtle differences please?

Comment: There's quite a range of meanings across *approcher* and *s'approcher*. [The extensive WordReference list](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/approcher) is a good start. One issue with WR is that it doesn't often tell you which meanings are more prominent. The one I encounter most often in terms of capturing the usual English "to approach X" is "s'approcher de X".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["approcher" ou "s'approcher"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25920/approcher-ou-sapprocher)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb ***approcher*** can be used a reflexive way and means that the subject gets closer to the object.

> *Je m'approche de la fenêtre.* (I'm getting near the window.)

The opposite is:

> *Je m'éloigne de la fenêtre.*

While the same sentence might have been used a non reflexive way in the past, you don't really say in modern French (at least in France but it seems to sound odd in Canadian French too):

> <s>*J'approche la fenêtre.*</s>

or

> <s>*J'approche de la fenêtre.*</s>

These forms might be possible when *approcher* means to move something near something else, in which case the reflexive form is not possible, e.g.:

> *J'approche la chaise de la table* (or better: *je rapproche la chaise de la table*) I move the chair toward the table.

The opposite is:

> *J'éloigne/écarte la chaise de la table*

There are a few cases where ***approcher (de)*** is equivalent to ***s'approcher de***:

> *Il approche la cinquantaine.* (he is approaching his fifties)
>
> *Il approche de la cinquantaine.*
>
> *Il s'approche de la cinquantaine.*

Some where there is a nuance:

> *Il approche son client.* He approaches his customer (The approach is deliberate and likely the first step of a plan).
>
> *Il se rapproche de son client*. (He is getting closer physically or emotionally. That might not be deliberate.)
>
> *L'avion approche de Paris.* (meaning *L'avion est en approche de Paris*. Its pilot is preparing the landing procedure)
>
> *L'avion se rapproche de Paris.* (The plane is getting closer to Paris location but that might not be its actual destination.)

Some other where the reflexive form is unused:

> *Il approche le problème sous divers angles* (also *il aborde le problème...*)
>
> <s>*Il s'approche du problème sous divers angles.*</s>

See also ["approcher" ou "s'approcher"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25920/approcher-ou-sapprocher)

Comment: Je trouve _j'approche la fenêtre_ étrange. Même _j'approche de la fenêtre_, quoique moins, je pense que je le dirais peut-être avec des lieux en auto, du genre _j'approche de Québec_. Je suis pas certain...

Comment: Il y a des [exceptions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+approche+de+Paris%2C&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20approche%20de%20Paris%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20approche%20de%20Paris%3B%2Cc0), et si cela se trouve dans les textes, ce doit être plus courant encore dans la langue parlée.

Comment: @LPH Aucune règle ne dit qu'une expression rare à l'écrit doive moins l'être à l'oral. *On approche de Paris* se dit surtout quand on est dans un véhicule, une raison pour laquelle *on approche du bureau* n'est pas idiomatique.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is certainly true, but to a point : The TLFi classifies the meanings into two parts;

> I. Emplois vieillis, littér. ou figés.
>   A. Emploi trans.
>   B. Emplois trans. ind. Approcher de…
>
> II. Emplois vivants
>   A. Emploi pronom. S'approcher de…
>   B. Emploi intrans. Approcher.

However, as it can be seen from the categories, "approcher" as an intransitive verb is still quite current; although a preference is apparently given to the pronominal verb in the spoken language (personal impression) this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+approcha+de+*%2Cil+s%27approcha+de+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cil%20approcha%20de%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20sa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20ses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20Paris%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cil%20s%27approcha%20de%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20lui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20M.%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s%27approcha%20de%20sa%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cil%20approcha%20de%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20l'%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20sa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20ses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20approcha%20de%20Paris%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cil%20s'approcha%20de%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20l'%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20lui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20M.%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20s'approcha%20de%20sa%3B%2Cc0) shows that in print the intransitive verb is  sometimes used more frequently: "approcha de sa", "… de son", "…de cette".

There is no subtle difference as far as I can tell; the meaning is the same; I can impute this replacement to nothing else than the vagaries of usage.

For instance, from the two following possibilities only [the second is correct](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apr%C3%A8s+avoir+approch%C3%A9%2Capr%C3%A8s+s%27%C3%AAtre+approch%C3%A9&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capr%C3%A8s%20avoir%20approch%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capr%C3%A8s%20s%27%C3%AAtre%20approch%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Capr%C3%A8s%20avoir%20approch%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capr%C3%A8s%20s'%C3%AAtre%20approch%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) (sense and usualness) (correction due to user **jlliagre**, see comments);

- <s>Après avoir approché du bureau il y a posé un livre.</s>
- Après s'être approché du bureau il y a posé un livre.

Comment: @jlliagre As far as I can see, there is no tangible reason for the replacement of the transitive verb by the pronominal verb; maybe I'll learn something interesting in your answer.

Comment: You two disagree, so then are the two not actually equivalent or interchangeable?

Comment: No, they aren't. Only the second sentence is acceptable. Every native French speaker would spot the incorrectness of the first one.

Comment: @jlliagre I think I see what you mean; those forms do not belong to the so called "emplois vivants". I change my answer.