# Why use pronominal verb such as “s'approchent de”

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I bumped into as sentence as such:

> Ils s'approchent de une vendeuse

My question is what is that *s'* doing in there.

I guess it is as pronominal verb. but then the sentence would mean “They get themselves close to the vendor”

Is it necessary to use pronominal verb in this case? Or is there a specific meaning added to the sentence by the usage of *s'*?

Comment: Where did you see that sentence? Because no French speaking person can have written *de une vendeuse*, there's  an elision in *de+une*. If not your question, which is basically asking for the difference between *s'approcher de * and *approcher*,  [already has an answer of FL](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36452/358).

Comment: yeah your right the text was written as " Ils s'approchent d'une vendeuse." I made a mistake.
Thanks for the link!