# Differences between (s')approcher vs. (se) rapprocher. Disregard the meaning of "approcher de nouveau"

Tags: différence

Disregard the senses of « approcher de nouveau » and « grossir », because these are exclusive to *rapprocher*. I know that *rapprocher* [= *re + approcher*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rapprocher#Etymology).

The following senses of *rapproche* look identical to *approcher*! In EACH following sentence, I feel that *(s')approcher* CAN FITLY REPLACE `(se) rapprocher` without changing meaning. Am I correct? Why, or why not?

#### Examples from [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/rapprocher)

> **4. Tendre à être plus près (d'un but, un principe).** `Se rapprocher` de son idéal.
>
> **5. Se rapprocher de : présenter une analogie avec, ressembler à.** C'est ce qui `se rapproche` le plus de la vérité.

#### Examples from [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapproche)

> ## A. 1. [⋮]
>
> b) Empl. pronom. Se rapprocher (de qqc./de qqn). Venir plus près de quelque chose. Se rapprocher (l'un de l'autre, les uns des autres).
>
> > Devenir plus proche l'un de l'autre. Son nez remonta, ses sourcils `se rapprochèrent`, sa bouche se distendit, et elle se mit à pleurer (Schwob, *Monelle*, 1894, p. 32).
>
> > Le soleil, `se rapprochant` de l'horizon, couvrait la terre d'une lumière orange (Lacretelle, *Silbermann*, 1922, p. 164).
>
> > Joseph le vit tâtonner si maladroitement avec sa clef qu'il `se rapprocha` pour l'observer de plus près (Green, *Moïra*, 1950, p. 27).

> ## 2. P. ext.
>
> #### a) Faire paraître plus proche à la vue.
>
> > Le beau temps garda son équilibre et les Pyrénées basses, sombres et bleues `rapprochèrent` l'horizon (Jammes, *Mém.*, 1922, p. 65).
>
> [⋮]
>
> Empl. pronom. Paraître plus proche.
>
> > À l'heure où les montagnes `se rapprochent`, bleues au-dessus des arbres, Clotilde se promenait aves Scaeffs (Chardonne, *Femmes*, 1961, p. 35).

> ## 3. Vieilli ou empl. techn. Rapprocher qqc./qqn
>
> ##### a) Se rapprocher de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un; venir plus près de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un.
>
> > Bientôt j'aperçus dans le Nord-Nord-Est une île qui n'était portée sur aucune carte (...), je cherchai à la `rapprocher`, mais elle était exactement dans le lit du vent (Voy. La Pérouse, t. 2, 1797, p. 390).
>
> > ♦ Au fig. Wagner allait la `rapprocher` [la nature], s'en saisir, la faire entrer dans un orchestre, l'asservir aux plus hautes idées musicales (Proust, Prisonn., 1922, p. 160).

> ## B. [⋮]
>
> ### 2. Acheminer vers un temps donné, vers un événement.
>
> > À mesure qu'il entendait sonner les heures qui le `rapprochaient` du moment de l'action, il se sentait allègre et dispos (Stendhal, *Chartreuse*, 1839, p. 364).
>
> > Pour la première fois, l'idée que s'écoulait en lui le temps qui le `rapprochait` de la mort ne le sépara pas du monde (Malraux, *Cond. hum.*, 1933, p. 430).

> ## C. [⋮]
>
> ### 4. Acheminer vers (un certain état, un but, un modèle).
>
> > Un penchant aveugle, autant que le hasard, vous `rapproche` souvent d'une perverse nature. Il faut combattre ce penchant, puisque l'on ne peut fuir le hasard des rencontres (Delacroix, *Journal*, 1854, p. 229).
>
> > De chaque jour, en effet, il attend non pas qu'il le `rapproche` de la perfection, mais qu'il lui révèle quelque chose de nouveau sur son cœur (Massis, *Jugements*, 1924, p. 102).
>
> − Empl. pronom. Être près d'atteindre quelque chose, de faire quelque chose; tendre vers quelque chose.
>
> > [Notre esprit] commence presque toujours par les opinions les plus erronées; et ce n'est que par des réformes successives qu'il `se rapproche` petit à petit de la vérité (Destutt de Tr., *Idéol.* 3, 1805, p. 166).
>
> > Je lui dis nettement que je me suis `rapproché` de l'idée du mariage (Montherl., *Démon bien*, 1937, p. 1253).

I read
["approcher" ou "s'approcher"](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25920), [Approcher vs. s’approcher](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36452).

Comment: You cannot fitly replace a transitive verb with a  pronominal verb, even if the action is perceived as similar the point of view that is conveyed is different, the subject of the verb is different. So, from my point of view, having  *approcher/s'approcher* & *rapprocher/se rapprocher* all in one question raises different issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Se rapprocher` de son idéal.

The meaning is that of relative action, whereas with "approcher" it is that of "absolute" action. "s'approcher de son idéal" means nothing more than the progression that has been gone through results in a closer and closer position. On the other hand, "se rapprocher de son idéal" means that in a given progression there might have been some straying from the goal of getting closer, possibly a period of stagnation, and that from some point on, the tendancy in the progression was of getting nearer to the ideal.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/re-)) **re-** d) [Le préf. exprime l'approche ou l'éloignement par rapport à un repère] V. rapprocher (se), rattraper, réchapper de, regagner (le terrain perdu), rejoindre, remonter (des concurrents), retarder (sens temporel).

(The following has been ignored: "c) [Le préf. exprime le retour à une position init., à partir d'une position opposée]
− [La base est un verbe à init. vocalique] V. rabaisser (ce qui est haut ou trop haut), rabattre (ce qui est levé), ramener (ce qui s'éloigne), rapprocher (ce qui est loin), rehausser, réintroduire, rouvrir, etc. et aussi").

2. C'est ce qui `se rapproche` le plus de la vérité.

Here is the definition.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapprocher)) − Empl. pronom. Être près d'atteindre quelque chose, de faire quelque chose; tendre vers quelque chose.

In pronominal use, "approcher" has never this figurative meaning; this can be checked by means of a verification of the following section in the TLFi, which will not be duplicated here in reason of its length.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/approcher)) **II.** − Emplois vivants
> A.− Emploi pronom. S'approcher de...

3. Devenir plus proche l'un de l'autre. Son nez remonta, ses sourcils `se rapprochèrent`, sa bouche se distendit, et elle se mit à pleurer (Schwob, *Monelle*, 1894, p. 32).

Eyebrows are, to begin with, close to one another (relatively close); the getting closer is considered to be made relatively to this position of nearness. This point of view is more or less arbitrary and in another language, perhaps English, there is a way to express this idea; however, a current fashion to say this does take into account this idea of initial nearness ("his eyebrows grew clos**er**").

4. Le soleil, `se rapprochant` de l'horizon, couvrait la terre d'une lumière orange (Lacretelle, *Silbermann*, 1922, p. 164).

In this case both verbs can be used without a change in meaning.

5. Joseph le vit tâtonner si maladroitement avec sa clef qu'il `se rapprocha` pour l'observer de plus près (Green, *Moïra*, 1950, p. 27).

Both verbs can be used without a change in meaning; if however, in the context, it has been made explicit that Joseph had come close to whatever character is implied, then  "rapprocher" is more idiomatic.

- Joseph se tenait non loin de lui, à un pas ; il le vit tâtonner si maladroitement avec sa clef qu'il se rapprocha pour l'observer de plus près

6. Le beau temps garda son équilibre et les Pyrénées basses, sombres et bleues rapprochèrent l'horizon (Jammes, *Mém.*, 1922, p. 65).

This figurative meaning ("faire paraitre plus près") does not exist for "approcher". In order to begin to convince oneself of that the entry of the TLFi for "approcher" must be screened.

7. À l'heure où les montagnes `se rapprochent`, bleues au-dessus des arbres, Clotilde se promenait aves Scaeffs (Chardonne, *Femmes*, 1961, p. 35).

As in "6."

8. Bientôt j'aperçus dans le Nord-Nord-Est une île qui n'était portée sur aucune carte (...), je cherchai à la rapprocher, mais elle était exactement dans le lit du vent (Voy. La Pérouse, t. 2, 1797, p. 390).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapprocher)) a) Se rapprocher de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un; venir plus près de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un.

The idea of a beacon is  manifest in this case also (the island being visible the ship or boat must be close to it).

9. Au fig. Wagner allait la rapprocher [la nature], s'en saisir, la faire entrer dans un orchestre, l'asservir aux plus hautes idées musicales (Proust, *Prisonn.*, 1922, p. 160).

There are no figurative senses of "approcher" that will do.

10. a) À mesure qu'il entendait sonner les heures qui le `rapprochaient` du moment de l'action, il se sentait allègre et dispos (Stendhal, *Chartreuse*, 1839, p. 364).

b) Pour la première fois, l'idée que s'écoulait en lui le temps qui le rapprochait de la mort ne le sépara pas du monde (Malraux, *Cond. hum.*, 1933, p. 430).

The verb "rapprocher" takes on a new meaning, that of an idiom, and there is no  such definition for "approcher".

11. Un penchant aveugle, autant que le hasard, vous `rapproche` souvent d'une perverse nature. Il faut combattre ce penchant, puisque l'on ne peut fuir le hasard des rencontres (Delacroix, *Journal*, 1854, p. 229).

De chaque jour, en effet, il attend non pas qu'il le `rapproche` de la perfection, mais qu'il lui révèle quelque chose de nouveau sur son cœur (Massis, *Jugements*, 1924, p. 102).

12. a) Notre esprit] commence presque toujours par les opinions les plus erronées; et ce n'est que par des réformes successives qu'il `se rapproche` petit à petit de la vérité (Destutt de Tr., *Idéol*. 3, 1805, p. 166).

b) Je lui dis nettement que je me suis `rapproché` de l'idée du mariage (Montherl., Démon bien, 1937, p. 1253).

In this present case, a figurative meaning of "approcher" exists that can be taken as synonymous.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/approcher)) c) Au fig.
> − Littér. Être près d'atteindre... (une certaine valeur, un idéal ...)
> ... quelle plus grande preuve de modestie puis-je donner que de brûler un ouvrage qui m'a coûté des années de travail? Et quel plus grand hommage peut recevoir de moi l'admirable modèle dont je ne puis jamais approcher? Florian, *Fables*,1792, p. 16.